# Laplace Transform of $f(t) = u(\sin(2t))$?

Tags: laplace-transform

What is the Laplace Transform of $f(t) = u(\sin(2t))$?

I'm confused how to proceed further? because $u(t)=0$ for t<0. What does having $\sin(2t)$ in argument mean?

Or $u$ has to be taken as unknown function?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: I've always seen $u$ defined as $1$ for $t>0$, and $0$ for $t<0$. But this (or another) definition should be given to you, not guessed at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $u(t) = 1$ for positive $t$, and $0$ otherwise, then $u(\sin(2t)) = 1$ whenever $\sin(2t)$ is positive.

That is, $f(t) = 1$ whenever $2t$ is in one of the intervals $(0,\pi),\;(2\pi,3\pi),\;(4\pi,5\pi),\;(-2\pi,-\pi),\;\cdots$

meaning $t$ is in one of the intervals $(0,\frac\pi2),\;(\pi,\frac{3\pi}2),\;(2\pi,\frac{5\pi}2),\;(-\pi,-\frac\pi2),\;\cdots$

and $f(t) = 0$ otherwise. This is a square wave.

Comment: Yes i wrote the defn of step function wrongly. And Thanks for Solution

Comment: The Laplace transform of $f$ is not a square wave; I just set up the problem for you to finish. Or did you already? If so, click on the check mark to "accept" this answer.

Comment: Yes i understood that f(t) is a square wave